# How to verify a long registry entry in powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, registry, regedit

I'm trying to verify a registry path in powershell script, but it always return false even if the registry exist.
To a specific character it gives true , beyond that it returns false

Here is the following code:-

```
Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\'
 Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Bootstrap Release\1033\CurrentVersion'
```

It returns true for the first line, but false beyond that even if the registry exists.
Is there any way to verify the long registry path as well?

Comment: Both of those commands work fine on my machine (`PS v5.0`), what PowerShell version are you using? Are you able to view the path with `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Also can get the path back from `Resolve-Path`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 'test-path' to test existance of registry values. Use test-path to test **registry keys only**

You should use custom function to test registry values, see: [Test if registry value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648931/test-if-registry-value-exists)