# Try returning the existing registry value from functoin otherwise catch and continue

Tags: function, powershell

We can first [check if registry value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648931/test-if-registry-value-exists) then re-query the registry value and return from the function. Is there a way to do it inline, avoiding registry query twice? I am getting exception from the following script:

```
function Get-VisualStudioPath
{
  foreach($i in @("15.0", "14.0", "12.0", "11.0", "10.0"))
  {
    try
    {
      return (gp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" -Name $i).$i
    }
    catch { <# ignore #> }
  }
  return $null;
}
```

Exception on system, where I have only VS2012 (aka v. `11.0`) installed:

```
gp : Property 15.0 does not exist at path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7.
At line:6 char:12
+ ...     return (gp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (15.0:String) [Get-ItemProperty], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

Expected behavior:

Returns the value of `11.0`.

On the same system, `(gp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" -Name "11.0")."11.0"` returns the desired value. The script is throwing for the non-existent version of VS.

#### Update

With @Andrei's solution, I have extended the function to make it standard cmdlet, and return selected version and path:

```
function Get-VisualStudioVersionAndPath
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [Alias("gvsvp")]
  PARAM()
  process
  {
    foreach($v in @("15.0", "14.0", "12.0", "11.0", "10.0"))
    {
      try
      {
        $path = (gp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" -Name $v -EA Stop).$v
        return @($v, $path)
      }
      catch { <# ignore #> }
    }

    throw [System.InvalidOperationException] "Couldn't find suitable version of Visual Studio!"
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
# thorws exception, when neither of 2017, 2015, 2013, 2012 or 2010 are found
$VSPath,$VSVersion = Get-VisualStudioVersionAndPath
# or compactly
$vsv,$vsp = gvsvp

# doesn't throw due to -EA support
$VSPath,$VSVersion = Get-VisualStudioVersionAndPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# or compactly
$vsv,$vsp = gvsvp -ea 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Get-VisualStudioPath
{
  foreach($i in @("15.0", "14.0", "12.0", "11.0", "10.0"))
  {
    try
    {
      return (gp "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" -Name $i -ErrorAction Stop).$i
    }
    catch { <# ignore #> }
  }
  return $null;
}
```

More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/).

Comment: Thanks! The compact form `-EA` also works here. :)

Comment: And even more :) It's possible to use the next abridgement: `-ea 1`. Run the following code snippet `[enum]::getvalues([Management.Automation.ActionPreference])|%{"$_="+[int]$_}`.

Comment: Great, I have updated the question with extended function to locate VS. :D